# Jenkins fails to connect to a remote repository

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

In the "Source code management" settings of the configuration for my Jenkins I have added a Git repository by selecting its URL and credentials. For some reason, right after adding them I get a notification that says:

[image]

Jenkins is running on a VM. When I navigate to Jenkins's workspaces and I locate my Repo, right there I can run all kind of Git commands(PULL, FETCH etc.) without any problem. I am using exactly the same credentials as the ones used in the Configuration menu of Jenkins.

What could be the reason for that behavior? Never happened to me before.

If I enter another repository URL address it is fine.

Comment: 'Not Found' error leads me to believe that it is a url typo.  At least focus your troubleshooting on the connection/URL dont look at the creds being the issue at this time.

Comment: @Eddie Well, it can not be a URL typo since I copy/paste the URL.